# agregar imagen de mi base de datos en excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, phpexcel

Tengo el siguiente codigo mediante el cual genero un reporte de excel con informacion almacenada en mi base de datos.

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que al generar el archivo excel me muestre la imagen en la columna F ya que en mi base datos solo esta almacenada el nombre de la imagen y la imagen esta almacenada en una carpeta en mi servidor.

La direccion que utilizo para extraer las fotos en mi aplicacion al mostrarlas es la siguiente

`http://172.30.99.131/upload_file/RestApi/upload/`

Les agredeceria si pudieran ayudarme.

Index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'conexion.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM plan_embarque,tb_image";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

$excel = new Spreadsheet();
$hojaActiva = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$hojaActiva->setTitle("Imagenes");

$hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(11.29);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('A1', 'RAMPA');
$hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(10.29);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('B1', 'TRAILER');
$hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(9.29);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('C1', 'PLANTA');
$hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(14.14);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('D1', 'FECHA ENVIO');
$hojaActiva->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(10.43);
$hojaActiva->setCellValue('E1', 'IMAGEN');

$fila = 2;

while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $rows['rampa']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $rows['trailer']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $rows['plant_code']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $rows['prog_date']);
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('E'.$fila, $rows['name']);
    $fila++;
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ReporteEnvios.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;

?>
```

Asi se ve mi excel cuando lo genero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En primer lugar, estás usando una librería ya descontinuada, me refiero a PHPExcel, deberías considerar el uso de [PHPSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). Intentar hacer funcionar un código basado en una librería obsoleta no es otra cosa que tiempo perdido, si es que llega a funcionar.

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet) del manejo de imágenes con la nueva librería. Vale la pena aprovechar problemas en el código para dar un salto de calidad. Luego lo vas a agradecer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario revisare la nueva libreria

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo deja lo reviso